# showmount is not showing any files while setting up and automount nfs server

Tags: nfs, automount

I was following a bunch of live sessions about how to setup an nfs server. I created the file exports in /etc/exports and the file contained the following:

```
/data    -rw     *(rw,no_root_sqush)
```

I have the directory and all the files of /data setup properly in there, I have started the nfs server.

```
systemctl start nfs
```

and it didn't return any errors, but when I tried to check the showmount for the /data I couldn't find any list of /data in the showmount

```
showmount -e localhost
```

this is what I get,

```
Export list for localhost:
```

but no /data in the list.

then I wanted to check the status of the nfs server since it didn't give any errors:

```
systemctl status -l nfs
```

and the result was:

```
    ● nfs-server.service - NFS server and services
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nfs-server.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Mon 2017-03-13 04:09:47 EDT; 2min 44s ago
  Process: 4197 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rpc.nfsd $RPCNFSDARGS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 4193 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/exportfs -r (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 4197 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/nfs-server.service

Mar 13 04:09:47 dhcppc6 systemd[1]: Starting NFS server and services...
Mar 13 04:09:47 dhcppc6 exportfs[4193]: exportfs: /etc/exports:1: unknown keyword "no_root_sqush"
Mar 13 04:09:47 dhcppc6 systemd[1]: Started NFS server and services.
```

so whenever I try to mount the /data through:

```
mount localhost:/data /mnt
```

the result was

```
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting localhost:/data
```

Even though I'm accessing as a root.

Is there anything missing here that I did make while setting the nfs server that make me unable to mount its data?

Regarding the mounting:
I have added the following line in `/etc/auto.master`:

```
/nfsserver      /etc/auto.nfsserver
```

and I created a new file `/etc/auto.nfsserver` and also added the line:

```
blah    -rw     localhost:/data
```

to prepare everything for the mounting, so I could mount the nfs server. But any help here would much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in the following line Is a typo:

```
/data    -rw     *(rw,no_root_sqush)
```

> Mar 13 04:09:47 dhcppc6 exportfs[4193]: exportfs: /etc/exports:1:
>   unknown keyword "no_root_sqush"

As in the [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/5/exports)

> The only options that are permitted to vary in this way are ro, rw,
>   no_root_squash, root_squash, and all_squash.

You should use `no_root_squash` instead

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have dumped a lot of information, and disregarded the fact that it might be a typo.

Comment: @MohamedR.Abdelhameed - happy to see that I helped you :) if my answer helped you please [accept](http://serverfault.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer